# Color not applying to first column in table according to props

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to color in the first column of my row according to a value that is calculated. If it is even, the color is white. If it is odd, the color should be gray. This way we can create a "zebra striping" effect. The first column is also supposed to "stick" and be present when the user scrolls right. The column is colored by default according to the row, so at first, the colors look correct. However, when I scroll, the cells are suddenly transparent like so:
Un-scrolled:
[image]

After scrolling:
[image]

Here is the code where I tried setting the color of each cell according to the props.index value:

```
export const TDHeader = styled.td<any>`
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid ${theme.gray.lightmedium};
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(147, 147, 147, 0.7);
  border-style: ${props => (props.borderTop ? "solid" : "none")} solid
    ${props => (props.borderBottom ? "solid" : "none")}
    ${props => (props.hideLeft ? "none" : "solid")};
  background-color: ${props =>
    props.index % 2 === 0 ? "rgba(242, 242, 242, 1)" : "rgba(147, 147, 147, 1)"}

  ...
  }
`;
```

And here is an example of where the cell is used:

```
<Row viewer={viewer} index={level.level + zebraStripOffset}>
              <TDHeader
                index={level.level + zebraStripOffset}
                className="bold"
                rowSpan={2}
                hideLeft={true}
                borderBottom={isLastRow}
              >
                {level.level}
              </TDHeader>
...
```

As you can see, the color clearly isn't being applied. Am I passing around props wrong, or what could be going on?

Comment: please isnert a minimal reproduciable code snippet. Why not simply use `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd) as a selector?  Also you talk about columns while in the pictures the rows are colored zebra striped wise.

Comment: Sorry, I know the rows are, I just want the first "column" to retain its color even when I scroll, which it's not doing. The individual data cell itself becomes transparent.

Comment: Why are you doing this with code? You should be using the `:nth-child(even)` CSS property. You are overthinking this massively

Comment: @Laif someone else wrote the code, for what it's worth. I agree, this entire table I'm working on is a bit convoluted but fixing it is out of the scope of this issue.

Comment: @JimmyBlundell you can just add a style tag to the table, no ?